# CGRectContainsPoint using shape opposed to frame

Tags: objective-c, frame, uibezierpath, cgrect, skshapenode

So we have our detection here

```
-(void)checkInFOVWithPlayer:(Player *)player andEnemy:(Player *)enemy {
    SKNode *fovNode = [player childNodeWithName:player.playersFOVName];

    SKNode *node = [self childNodeWithName:@"enemy"];

    CGPoint newPosition = [self convertPoint:node.position toNode:fovNode.parent];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(fovNode.frame, newPosition)) {
        [self playerAimAtEnemy:enemy withPlayer:player];
    }
}
```

And our implementation for the field of vision

```
SKShapeNode *fov = [SKShapeNode node];
UIBezierPath *fovPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[fovPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[fovPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(fovOpposite *-1, fovDistance)];
[fovPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(fovOpposite, fovDistance)];
[fovPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
fov.path = fovPath.CGPath;
fov.lineWidth = 1.0;
fov.strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor];
fov.antialiased = NO;
fov.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor];
fov.alpha = 0.2;
fov.name = @"playerFOV";
[_playerImage addChild:fov];
```

Now, this works. However, the detection range for the "field of vision" is not actually the boundaries of the BezierPath, it's in fact the CGRect that creates the image.

So, the detection will run, even if it's outside of the visual field of vision.

I'm curious as to whether there's an easy fix for this, as I don't really want to go down physics body paths if I don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out what was required.

I had to redraw the path and optimise it for each frame, after that;

```
if (CGPathContainsPoint(fovPath.CGPath, nil, newPosition, NO)) {}
```

Ended my problems.